# How do I stop Visual Studio from creating XML Documentation files in a Release build?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

When i build my application in `Release` mode i get the folder flooded with .xml files, Is there anyway to stop that ?

Comment: What kind of .xml files? And do you also get them when you build in Debug mode?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it looks like an XML related to the assembly

Comment: It would be interesting if you were more explicit. Like, what's the name of one of these files? What do the first few lines of content look like?

Comment: @JohnSaunders AutoMapper.dll has AutoMapper.xml, HtmlAgilityPack.dll has HtmlAgilityPack.xml

Comment: Is this difficult for you? Post the first few lines of one of those files.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>HtmlAgilityPack</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttributeCollection">
            <summary>
            Represents a combined list and collection of HTML nodes.
            </summary>
        </member>

Comment: @JohnSaunders assembly documentation...

Comment: Thanks. You could have said that ten minutes ago. Your question then becomes, "How do I stop Visual Studio from creating XML Documentation files in a Release build?"

Comment: Did you resolve this? I can't figure out how to remove them either

Answer (score 2):

If it's a VB.Net project, there's a checkbox under Project Settings -> Compile called "Generate XML documentation file". If it's a C# project it's under Project Settings -> Build XML documentation file, where you specify your own path.

Keep in mind that intellisense uses those to give you the summary, paramref, and other hints that you've put as xml docs over your function.

Comment: it is c#, and Build XML Doc File is unchecked so why it generates those files ?!

Comment: I just tried the option out, and turning it off stops them from being generated on my machine. Are you positive we're talking about the same checkbox? Here's a screenshot of the one I mean: http://grab.by/yPTk

Comment: the problem is that the xml files is generated for the refrenced assemblies too...

Comment: Well, of course, so change those projects as well.  Or delete them again in a Post build event.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I can't figure out how to remove them either

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `csproj`file to include a `AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions` tag  in the release build definition

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
      <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
          <!-- Prevent default XML documentation files to be copied to output-->
          .pdb
      </AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
```